# How to reduce C# winform label spacing between labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know is there any setting to reduce the spacing between two labels. As my picture show, my label "ATC" is hidden by the label with "0". But actually the 0 doesn't really occupy the space but with empty space.

I tried Margin and Padding of label but can't help.

[image: Picture for my program]

Comment: A font reserves space for the descenders (gjp etc) and diacritics.  "0" doesn't have any but that's but an accident.  Setting the bottom label's BackColor property to Transparent and moving it to the front so it overlaps the label with the "0" is a workaround.   Or turning off AutoSize on the top label so you can intentionally remove the space for the descenders.  Keep in mind that Label is but a point-and-click convenience, expensive and inflexible.  If you want to stack pixels then TextRenderer.DrawText() is always the best approach

Comment: thanks. I understand your method, let me try it.

Comment: is your label `0` auto resize ? why not try configuring the font instead. try to set a text on label before run the application. so you can see what size font you need to see.

Comment: yes.. you are right. But because I will dealing with MDI form. The form is one of MDI child form of my main form. I dynamically  create the child form and two labels inside it. And get that issue.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! When I put the bottom label "ATC" to the front, it help the issue and reduce the overlapping. I am new to window form, let me have a look to the TexRender.DrawText() you suggest. You may make it to answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't really understand what you want, maybe :  focus on label 0, right mouse button click, **sent to back** or label AIC **send to back**

Comment: If you don't understand the question then you should ask for clarification in a comment, not add an answer that may be incorrect or irrelevant.